# How do I remove a border on an Ion-Toolbar?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need help removing the border from the `ion-toolbar` in the `ion-header` in Ionic v4 (4.0.9).

My objective is to remove this:

[image: my two toolbars with borders]

In my code I have a `ion-header` with two `ion-toolbar`. I've tried everything the `no-border` attribute inside `ion-header` and `ion-toolbar`.

I've also tried adding the attributes to the .scss of my page like the following:

```html
<ion-header no-border-bottom no-border-top no-border>
  <ion-toolbar color="dark" no-border-bottom no-border-top no-border>
    <img src="../../assets/icoUserLogin.png" alt="Logo Aikox" slot="start" witdh="20%" />
    <ion-title slot="primary">
      Test
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-toolbar class="ToolbarVerde" color="medium" no-border-bottom no-border-top no-border>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <img src="../../assets/icoListado.png" alt="Icono Listado" slot="start" width="70%" />
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      <span>test</span>
      <br />
      <span>test</span>
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button (click)="Nuevo()">
        <img src="../../assets/icoRefresh.png" alt="Icono Recargar" width="70%" /><br />
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="Nuevo()">
        <img src="../../assets/icoNew.png" alt="Añadir Parte de Trabajo" width="70%" /><br />
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

```css
.toolbar-background{
    --border-width: 0px !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
.toolbar-container{
    --padding-top: 0px !important;
    --padding-left: 0px !important;
    --padding-right: 0px !important;
    --padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.ToolbarVerde{
    --padding-top: 0px !important;
    --padding-left: 0px !important;
    --padding-right: 0px !important;
    --padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Hi this might help someone

```
<ion-header no-border >

</ion-header>
```

this remove the line in ionic4

Comment: no-border directive works for common pages, but not for modals.

Comment: @rochasdv It is working fine with the Modal pages too.

Comment: ionic 5 replace no-border with class="ion-no-border"

Answer (score 61):

In case any one is looking for Ionic 5 solution, do this:

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border">
</ion-header>
```

It removes border and shadow.

Answer (score 10):

Use this to remove the shadow:

```
ion-header {
  &.header-md:after {
    background: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this to remove the border:

```
ion-toolbar {
  --border-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it, for anyone having problems with this:

Add a class to your `<ion-toolbar class="ToolbarVerde"`, then in your .scss use the following:

```css
.ToolbarVerde{
    --padding-top: 0px !important;
    --padding-start: 0px !important;
    --padding-right: 0px !important;
    --padding-end: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">